# Is it safe to manually handle custom message sent from another thread

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to post message from one thread to a window in another thread via `PostThreadMessage`:

```
auto result = PostThreadMessage(mainThreadId, UserMessage::DestroyWindowRequest, 0, 0);
```

The MSDN says that

> Messages sent by PostThreadMessage are not associated with a window. As a general rule, messages that are not associated with a window cannot be dispatched by the DispatchMessage function.

So I cann't just receive my message. Is it safe to handle a message manually in a message loop as in code below?

```
INT_PTR AbstractWindow::TranslateMessageLoop()
{
    MSG msg{0};
    BOOL gotMessage = FALSE;
    static const BOOL hasError = -1;
    PostMessage(windowHandle, UserMessage::MessageLoopTranslated, 0, 0);
    while ((gotMessage = GetMessage(&msg, (HWND)NULL, 0, 0)) != 0 && gotMessage != hasError) {
    // Here I process a message. I assume that the message is always destined for my main window,
    // so I use it's handle - windowHandle.
        if (!msg.hwnd && msg.message == UserMessage::DestroyWindowRequest) {
            DestroyWindow(windowHandle);
        }
        else {
            if (PreTranslateMessage(&msg) == FALSE) {
                if (IsDialogMessage(windowHandle, &msg) == FALSE) {
                    TranslateMessage(&msg);
                    DispatchMessage(&msg);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

I know, MSDN suggest to use custom hooks, but it's a little bit overkill for me now.

Comment: Yes, that is safe.

Comment: Yes, it is safe, and is the only way you *can* process the message, since the window's message procedure will never see the message. Though, I would suggest posting the `DestroyWindowRequest` message to the actual window itself via `PostMessag()` (if feasible) and let its message procedure call `DestroyWindow()` on its own window, don't handle that in your message loop itself.

Comment: On a side note, your message loop does not need to handle the case of `GetMessage()` returning -1, because [it never will](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130322-00/?p=4873).

Comment: Not safe.  Quote: "Therefore, if the recipient thread is in a modal loop ... the messages will be lost".  A basic example of a modal loop is the one that's entered when you resize the window by dragging a corner.  Or drag+drop or a context menu, etc.  It is only safe if the thread does not own any windows.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090930-00/?p=16553